# Conversion vb6 to c#

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

I am trying to convert some vb6 code to c# and I am struggling a bit.
I have looked at this page below and others similar, but am still stumped.

[Why use hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243712/why-use-hex)

vb6 code below:

```
    Dim Cal As String
    Cal = vbNull

    For i = 1 To 8
        Cal = Cal + Hex(Xor1 Xor Xor2)
    Next i
```

This is my c# code - it still has some errors.

```
        string Cal = null;
        int Xor1 = 0;
        int Xor2 = 0;

        for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
            {
            Cal = Cal + Convert.Hex(Xor1 ^ Xor2);
            }
```

The errors are:

```
        Cal = Cal + Convert.Hex(Xor1 ^ Xor2 ^ 6);
```

Any advice as to why I cant get the hex to convert would be appreciated.
I suspect its my lack of understanding the .Hex on line 3 above and the "&H" on line 1/2 above.

Comment: What are the exceptions thrown?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note**: This answer was written at a point where the lines `Xor1 = CDec("&H" + Mid(SN1, i, 1))`
 and `Xor1 = Convert.ToDecimal("&H" + SN1.Substring(i, 1));` were still present in the question.

---

**What's the `&H`?**

In Visual Basic (old VB6 and also VB.NET), hexadecimal constants can be used by prefixing them with `&H`. E.g., `myValue = &H20` would assign the value `32` to the variable `myValue`. Due to this convention, the conversion functions of VB6 also accepted this notation. For example, `CInt("20")` returned the integer `20`, and `CInt("&H20")` returned the integer `32`.

Your code example uses `CDec` to convert the value to the data type `Decimal` (actually, to the Decimal subtype of `Variant`) and then assigns the result to an integer, causing an implicit conversion. This is actually not necessary, using `CInt` would be correct. Apparently, the VB6 code was written by someone who did not understand that (a) the `Decimal` data type and (b) representing a number in decimal notation are two completely different things.

---

**So, how do I convert between strings in hexadecimal notation and number data types in C#?**

To convert a hexadecimal string into a number use

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);   // use this instead of Convert.ToDecimal
```

In C#, there's no need to pad the value with "&H" in the beginning. The second parameter,`16`, tells the conversion function that the value is in base 16 (i.e., hexadecimal).

On the other hand, to convert a number into its hex representation, use

```
string hex = number.ToString("X");       // use this instead of Convert.ToHex
```

What you are using, `Convert.ToDecimal`, does something completely different: It converts a value into the `decimal` data type, which is a special data type used for floating-point numbers with decimal precision. That's not what you need. Your other method, `Convert.Hex` simply does not exist.

Comment: Cal += String.Format("{0:x}", Xor1 ^ Xor2 ^ 6);

Comment: Heinzi - Thank you!

Very much appreciated for taking the time to answer this.