# Reading byte arrays

Tags: c#

I am reading [async file i/o](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx). When writing to a file microsoft sets the bufferSize to 4096 bytes, but when reading they are using [0x1000]. I understand that this evaulates out to a 4k block just like seting the bufferSize to 4096.  **My question is why would they use the Hex Value instead of an integer?**

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand the question; the integer value 4096 (in decimal representation) is exactly 1000 (in hexadecimal representation). Is your question why sometimes the decimal representation and sometimes the hexadecimal representation is used?

Comment: They *are* using an integer, just in hexadecimal notation. As to why, its a stylistic choice in this case.  There are advantages to using hexadecimal notation, E.g. [Why use hex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243712/why-use-hex)

Comment: It's a simple constant. You can define same constant value in several ways, it absolutely does not matter which way is selected for the program, but it may be useful for a human reading source, e.g. constant `1 << 10` is more clear when operating with bits than `1024` (it say "10th bit set"). What really matter is a value, but you are not asking about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a practical standpoint, there is no difference.  They are the same value essentially.  However, as you probably know, computers tend to deal better with powers of two.  0x1000 just tends to render the idea more clearly than 4096.

This is the same reason why you would assign flags values using hexadecimal rather than their decimal values.  It makes it clear to the reader that its value is not a coincidentally clean number in hexadecimal but deliberate.  That said, don't use hexadecimal when it is completely irrelevant.

```
int numberOfCats = 0xA7;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So the answer is "computers tend to deal better" ?

Comment: @Sinatr no it is "Computer programmers tend to deal better". The computers deal better part was talking about powers of two, not using hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: @Sinatr No, technically no.  Computers don't care whether or not you're allocating an amount equivalent to a full memory page, 3/4ths of a memory page, or if you're writing over the BIOS.  However powers of two are nicer to deal with.