# What does setting a global variable equal to "0x0" do in C?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am currently going over some code that is written in C for a microcontroller and I am just trying to figure out why some of the variable are set equal to `0x0` and `0x1`. Can someone explain what that does?

Here's the code:

```
// Global variables
static bool volatile radio_busy;
int xx = 0x0;
int yy = 0x0;
int zz = 0x1;
bool flag = 1;
```

Comment: As to "why are the values 0x0 and 0x1 used to initialize certain variables", I suspect it depends very much on how they're used. It's easier to see which bits are set using hex - in 0x1 only lowest-order bit is set, and in 0x0 of course no bits are set. I *suspect* that these variables are used to access, set, or test some hardware-related values that the program uses, but only you can determine if that's correct and just what those hardware-related items might be. Best of luck.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Why use hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/243712/217324)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0x` is simply the prefix for [hexadecimal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) (base 16) rather than the default decimal (base 10).

So the array `{0x0, 0x1, 0xf, 0x42}` consists of the decimal values `0`, `1`, `15` (because the digits are `0-9`, and `a-f` equating to `10-15`) and `66` (from `4 * 16 + 2`).

People will often use hexadecimal when the intent is to operate on *bit patterns* rather than values (since one hexadecimal digit is fully contained within four bits) <sup>(a)</sup>.

The intent is not clear from the snippet you've given - it has annoyingly generic variable names which seem to give *no* meaningful indication as to what they're used for, something that's a hallmark of untrained programmers who seem to think large variable names somehow take up more space :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> For example, you might want to do the following to set bit `b5` (where bits are numbered from most significant `b7` to least significant `b0`) of a memory mapped location to `1`:

```
unsigned char *memLoc = 0xff00; // memory to modify.
unsigned char curr = *memLoc;   // get current.
curr = curr | 0x20;             // set ONLY b5, or with binary 00100000
*memLoc = curr                  // write it back.
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. And I completely agree with you about the variable names. I was given this code that was previously written by a former student. I'm just trying to go line by line to try to learn what it does.