# what does variable != 0xFF mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following if function that has a condition on an array of a data buffer, which stores data of a wav file

```
bool BFoundEnd = FALSE;

if (UCBuffer[ICount] != 0xFF){
    BFoundEnd = TRUE; 
                break;
            }
```

I was just confused on how 0xFF defines the condition inside the if function.

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? It just checks if `UCBuffer[ICount]` is not `0xFF` (255). Could you clarify? (Maybe a [mre] could help clarify your problem)

Comment: [Hexcode can be helpful to represent specific numbers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243712/why-use-hex). This code states that when the UC buffer is full (likely a uint8_t, which has 255 values, or 0xFF), then flag the buffer.

Comment: You should also use `true` and `false` instead of the uppercase macros, I guess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what does variable != 0xFF mean in C++?

`variable` is presumably an identifier that names a variable.

`!=` is the inequality operator. It results in false when left and right hand operands are equal and true otherwise.

`0xFF` is an integer literal. The `0x` prefix means that the literal uses hexadecimal system (base 16). The value is 255 in decimal system (base 10) and 1111'1111 in binary system (base 2). For more information about the base i.e. the radix of numeral systems, see wikipedia: [Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)

Answer (score 1):

Reread with comments:

```
// Remembers if buffer did end with 0xFF (255) or not.
bool BFoundEnd = FALSE;

// ... Later in loop.

// Actual check for above variable
// (where "if ... != ..." means if not equal).
if (UCBuffer[ICount] != 0xFF) {
    BFoundEnd = TRUE;
    // Cancels looping as reached buffer-end.
    break;
}

// ... Outside the loop.

// Handles something based on variable.
```

> In short, someone decided to make `255` a special value which marks the end of the buffer and/or array (instead of providing array length).